# How to store crypto wallet keys and other credentials safely on a VPS

Tags: python, ubuntu, server, cryptocurrency

Long story short, I developed a trading algorithm for crypto and now want to find a VPS from where the algorithm will be run. What precautions would one need to take to safely store the private key for your wallet? Do I need to fear the server administrators peeking inside my server?

Right now my program uses python-dotenv to load the credentials from a .env file, but is this enough safety? Since some VPS providers can be a bit dubious, especially given the fact that there are not much choices for the location I am looking for I really want to have maximum security. I've chosen the location because it is close to the data-feed physically.

I will be using Ubuntu for my server. All suggestions are welcome!

Comment: There is no way. If you don't own the server there is no way of stopping the owner from getting root and reading whatever they want. Even if you encrypt it at rest on disk a server admin can just cat the python script to see how to decrypt it. Even if you put it somewhere else and decrypt it into memory. Nothing stops root from dumping the memory of your process to get the keys. If you cant trust the server then you shouldnt host your things there.

Comment: So if you were in my position, what would you do? Do you have any tips for finding a reputable VPS service? This might sound paranoid but one rogue employee is all it takes for losing a substantial amount of savings, and given the hard-to-track status of cryptocurrency or the unfeasible costs associated with tracking this really worries me.

Comment: If you have the capital for it. host a small EC2 instance on AWS. its basically the same as a VPS except its actually owned by you. No one else has access

Comment: Thanks, I am currently looking into it and really appreciate the help. However, I find it hard to find documentation on  what exactly makes EC2 truly owned by the user. What is the terminology for the fact that you actually own it? And would you happen to know if DigitalOcean offers something similar as EC2? I am currently browsing their offering and am wondering if a VPC is the same as the thing you're suggesting. Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: See here for data protection in AWS: https://www.bridewellconsulting.com/aws-security-myths-part-1-data-security

Comment: Digital ocean probably has an offering but I'm not certain. Sorry.

Comment: @testfile Much obliged!